# How to avoid losing type information

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose I have something like this:

```
trait Cursor {
}

trait Column[T] {
   def read(cusor: Cursor): T
}

trait ColumnReader {
   def readColumns(columns: Product[Column[_]], cursor: Cursor): Iterable[Any] = {
       for (column <- columns) yield column.read(cursor)
   }
}
```

The problem of the `readColumns()` API is that I lose the type information, i.e., if I have this:

```
object columnString extends Column[String] {
   def read(cursor: Cursor): String = ...
}

object columnInt extends Column[Int] {
   def read(cursor: Cursor): Int = ...
}
```

An expression like `new ColumnReader().readColumns((columnString, columnInt))` returns `Iterable[Any]`.  I would like to return something typed like `Tuple2[String, Int]`, but don't know how.  I lose type information useful to the compiler.

Maybe a library like [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) could be useful.

I'm sure Scala has some tool for dealing on problems like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example using a shapeless `HList`

```
class Cursor

trait Column[T] {
  def read(cusor: Cursor): T
}

class CursorContainer(cursor: Cursor) {
  object mapper extends Poly1 {
    implicit def any[T] = at[Column[T]](_.read(cursor))
  }
}

class ColumnReader {

  def readColumns[T <: HList](columns: T, cursor: CursorContainer)(
    implicit m:Mapper[cursor.mapper.type, T]) = columns.map(cursor.mapper)
}

val columnString = new Column[String] {
  def read(cursor: Cursor): String = ???
}

val columnInt = new Column[Int] {
  def read(cursor: Cursor): Int = ???
}

val reader = new ColumnReader
val cursor =  new CursorContainer(new Cursor)
val result: String :: Int :: HNil =
  reader.readColumns(columnString :: columnInt :: HNil, cursor)
```

Comment: Thanks.  This answer is not trivial to someone new to Shapeless.  I have to try it.

Comment: Here is some doc for better understanding this: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values

Comment: Your solution works, but `foldLeft` is more flexible.  With `map`, I've had problems with stable identifiers in slighty more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a container that can take type parameters, e.g. Seq or List?

```
trait Cursor {
}

trait Column[T] {
   def read(cusor: Cursor): T
}

trait ColumnReader[T] {
   def readColumns(columns: Seq[Column[T]], cursor: Cursor): Iterable[T] = {
       for (column <- columns) yield column.read(cursor)
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the number of arguments and the type of them is variable.  A sequence has the same type arguments for every element.  A tuple structure is better, that's why I've used Product[Column[_]].

Comment: If you are giving columns of different types, then of course there is no common denominator other than Any. Shapeless might have some tricks for that, but in a nutshell, if you want to give Iterable[T] for a specific type T when you have as input columns of different types, then you have to come up with a rule of how these types should converge.

Comment: That's precisely what I'm looking for.  I'd like to replace Iterable[Any] with something with type info.

Comment: This seems to be an attempt to build a Table of values by separating the table data into typed columns. One could also write a Table by listing a sequence of Rows as in the question [how to create an HList of Lenses from an HList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222471/how-to-create-an-hlist-of-lenses-from-an-hlist). The advantage of this method should be that it is faster to get to any element of the table ( assuming IndexedSeq ). On the other hand, ordering of the data in this method remains an open question: how to order one column and have the other columns be reordered too

Answer (score 1):

You need an HList from Shapeless

Comment: I agree with you. I think you should develop your answer a little ;-) (example of usage, etc.?)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an Applicative if your number of columns is limited.

```
trait Column[T] {
  def read(c: Cursor) : Id[T]
}
object columnString extends Column[String]
{
  override def read(c: Cursor): Id[String] = "hello"
}

object columnInt extends Column[Int] {
  override def read(c: Cursor): Id[Int] = 3
}

type ColumnReader[T] = Reader[Cursor, T]

val readSpreadSheet1 : ColumnReader[(Int, String)] = Reader {
  c =>
    (columnInt.read(c) |@| columnString.read(c)) { (_,_)}
}

readSpreadSheet1(c)
```

would result in:

```
res1: scalaz.Id.Id[(Int, String)] = (3,hello)
```

I have also thrown in a little Reader definition, so that you do not need to care about passing around the instance of cursor when you read a row. On the downside, you need to know the types of your columns beforehand, but I think this would also be true when you use an HList.

Comment: I like more EECOLOR solution because it is more generic, but this is also interesting, even though I don't know still scalaz.